# Pg_dump and rsync backup script not working in anacron

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, cron, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

I have two sh scripts called Z-backup and lb. Z-backup is a script that I have placed in cron.daily so it is run as an anacron job and calls the lb script. The content of the Z-backup script is:

```
#!/bin/sh


set -e

# Anacron script to run a daily backup at boot time.

exec /home/chh1/bin/lb >/dev/null 2>&1

exit
```

The content of the lb script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Script to do a backup of PostgreSQL database crewdb and /home folder.
# ~/.pgpass file has been created to support pg_dump -w flag.

# The following if statement removes crewdb.backup.sql if it exists.

if [ -e /home/chh1/Dropbox/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql ]
then
    rm /home/chh1/Dropbox/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql
fi >/dev/null 2>&1


echo "PostgreSQL database crewdb backed up on $(date)" >> /home/chh1  
/logs/postgres_bak_log.txt
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d crewdb -w -C -F p -b -v -f    
~/Dropbox/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql >/dev/null 2>&1

echo "Home folder backed up on $(date)" >> /home/chh1   
/logs/home_bak_log.txt
rsync -acu --delete --exclude-from='/home/chh1/rsync_exclude.txt' /home/    
/media/chh1/f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422/home_backup/ >/dev/null    
2>&1


if [ -e /media/chh1/f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422/home_backup   
/chh1/Dropbox/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql ]
then
    rm /media/chh1/f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422/home_backup  
/chh1/Dropbox/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql
fi >/dev/null 2>&1


pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d crewdb -w -C -F p -b -v -f    
/media/chh1/f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422/home_backup/chh1/Dropbox   
/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql >/dev/null 2>&1


exit
```

If I just run lb in the terminal the script works just fine the way I want it to. (After running lb I run echo $? and get exit status 0). However the scheduled anacron job only gets partly executed and I can not figure out why this is the case. The log entries are created and the rsync command works, thus the home folder is backed up via anacron but not pg_dump.
When I run the pg_dump commands in lb and save stderr to a file such as:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d crewdb -w -C -F p -b -v -f    
~/Dropbox/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql 2>/pg_dump_errors.txt
```

and

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d crewdb -w -C -F p -b -v -f    
/media/chh1/f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422/home_backup/chh1/Dropbox   
/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql 2>/pg_dump_errors.txt
```

The /pg_dump_errors.txt file generates the same output for both pg_dump commands and shows the database dump but with no errors such as

```
head pg_dump_errors.txt && tail pg_dump_errors.txt

pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: identifying extension members
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators
pg_dump: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.timesheet    
          timesheet_date_linkid_fkey"
pg_dump: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.timesheet   
          timesheet_employee_functionid_fkey"
pg_dump: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.timesheet 
          timesheet_employeeid_fkey"
pg_dump: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.work work_categoryid_fkey"
pg_dump: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.work work_clientid_fkey"
pg_dump: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.work work_date_linkid_fkey"
pg_dump: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.work_expenses  
          work_expenses_date_linkid_fkey"
pg_dump: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.work_expenses 
          work_expenses_employeeid_fkey"
pg_dump: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.work_expenses 
          work_expenses_expense_categoryid_fkey"
pg_dump: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.work_expenses   
          work_expenses_workid_fkey"
```

My assumption here is that anacron (because of set -e in Z-backup) is not executing because of this but am not sure as I have really dumped stderr to /dev/null (in lb). All the other commands in lb don't generate any stderr output.

Additional information

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 119 Oct 13 13:57 /etc/cron.daily/z-backup
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chh1 chh1 1279 Oct 20 17:26 /home/chh1/bin/lb
-rw------- 1 chh1 chh1 68 Oct 21 06:00 /home/chh1/.pgpass

cat .pgpass
#hostname:port:database:username:password
*:*:crewdb:*:pg#$as(
```

`postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges

-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 crewdb    | postgres | UTF8     | en_NZ.UTF-8 | en_NZ.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | chh1=CTc/postgres
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_NZ.UTF-8 | en_NZ.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_NZ.UTF-8 | en_NZ.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_NZ.UTF-8 | en_NZ.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres`

```
sudo cat /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf

# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer 
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is not working? And why I am getting stderr output from pg_dump even when the backup seems to go ahead just fine. 
I much appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to change of pg_hba.conf to:

```
sudo grep ^[^#] /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
[sudo] password for chh1: 
local   all             all                                     trust 
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Now the anacron script works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`.pgpass` is per user. Is the Unix user that runs the scheduled script the same user as the one that's testing the script manually?

> And why I am getting stderr output from pg_dump even when the backup
>   seems to go ahead just fine

Because of the `-v` option. You should remove it, and also remove the `>/dev/null 2>&1` that cause potentially useful error messages to disappear, including in the upper caller.

Comment: The content of .pgpass is

`# hostname:port:database:username:password
*:*:crewdb:*:pg#$as(`

Comment: I removed -v but it still does not work. unix user is the same as the one testing the script (chh1)
`postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 crewdb    | postgres | UTF8     | en_NZ.UTF-8 | en_NZ.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | chh1=CTc/postgres`

Comment: Also
'-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 119 Oct 13 13:57 /etc/cron.daily/z-backup`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 chh1 chh1 1279 Oct 20 17:26 /home/chh1/bin/lb`
`-rw------- 1 chh1 chh1 68 Oct 21 06:00 /home/chh1/.pgpass'

Comment: @ChristianHick: if anacron is run by root, your may try copying /home/chh1/.pgpass to the home directory of root (normally /root on ubuntu). It must also have permission -rw------- and be owned be root.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks mate. I have copied ~.pgpass over to /.pgpass with root:root. So sudo cp ~.pgpass  /.pgpass and got rid of the -v flags. Once this works I will get rid of 2>&1. So I will be able to give an update tomorrow when anacron runs the daily task if these changes work.

Comment: Still not working! I now have a ~/.pgpass and a /.pgpass. I will try /,pgpass without ~/.pgpass.